# How to launch browser (IE) from Azure DevOps(VSTS tool)

Tags: azure-devops, devops, tosca

As part of Integrating the TOSCA (Automation tool) in the release pipeline, we are unable to kickoff the IE browser.

Comment: You should describe more about "we are unable to kickoff the IE browser", as there should be an error message with more information to show what exactly is the kind of problem you met. Also we need to know what build agent you use.

Comment: As part of GUI Tests(Automation),we are trying to run the below commands in "Command Line" task in VSTS:cd C:\Program Files (x86)\TRICENTIS\Tosca Testsuite\ToscaCI\Client\ToscaCIClient.exe -m local  while executing the above commands, expected result is to launch browser and run the test cases automatically.Actual Result:Process completed with exit code -1(Note: when we tried to run the same commands in cmd,we are able to launch the browser and test cases are getting passed) And, we have installed VSTS build agent configured with the user ID and pswd in windows service mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using hosted agents then it's not supported, you have to run the agents in interactive mode for the UI related things.

So just try to deploy an private agent and run the agent in interactive mode, please see [Deploy an agent on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts) for details.